# Sub-interface already in use on another host - brand new interface

Tags: networking, redhat, linux-networking, ifconfig

I created a sub-interface on a RHEL box, `eth0:1`, and copied the `eth0` config and changed all the settings to reflect `eth0:1` and the IP address. However, when I issue `ifup eth0:1` I receive this error:

```
[root@server-1 ~]# ifup eth0:1
Error, some other host already uses address 192.168.0.2.

[root@server-1 ~]# ping -c 1 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10000ms
```

However, when I issue: `ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.2 up` the command works and no errors. I would use the later command, but when I use it, it interferes with my primary, `eth0`, interface, and messes up the routing of my DNS traffic because its on the same subnet as the sub-interface `eth0:1`. I will make another post about the DNS issue.

These are the configs of the interfaces

```
[root@server-1 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="00:50:56:AF:0C:06"
IPADDR="192.168.0.1"
IPV6INIT="yes"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
DNS1="192.168.2.10"
DNS2="192.168.3.10"

[root@server-1 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0:1
DEVICE="eth0:1"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="00:50:56:AF:0C:06"
IPADDR="192.168.0.2"
IPV6INIT="yes"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
ONBOOT="no"
TYPE="Ethernet"
DNS1="192.168.2.10"
DNS2="192.168.3.10"
```

`ip addr show`

```
[root@server-1 network-scripts]# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:AF:0c:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0..255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.2.1/30 brd 192.168.2.3 scope global eth0:2
    inet 192.168.2.5/30 brd 192.168.2.7 scope global eth0:3
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe97:c06/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `ifcfg-eth0:1` file?

Comment: Configs posted.

Comment: Did you remove/change MAC addresses (HWADDR)?

Comment: No, I copied what is in the config files. When I created the configs, i just did a `cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0:1 then edited the name and IP address.

Comment: Please send output of "ip addr show" from that host. You can have multiple IP addresses on single interface without any sub-interfaces.

Comment: Added `ip addr show` output.

Comment: Simplify/remove the useless directives in the ifcfg-eth0:1, leave only DEVICE=eth0:1, IPADDR=192.168.0.2, IPV6INIT=yes, NETMASK=255.255.255.0, ONBOOT=yes, issue service network restart and test it again

Comment: I shouldn't leave the HWADDR in there as well? That was my experience with the other sub-interfaces I've had to create.

Comment: It's not necessary, you create a sub-interface of some interface which already has HWADDR defined.

Comment: So far, even after trimming the `ifcfg-eth0:1` file down to just those few lines, I'm getting that network interface is in use error. However, when I specified the `netmask` along with the ifconfig command, everything seems to be working just fine. I'm still testing a bit. The command I used was `ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` and I can resolve DNS names and such unlike before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is generated either by `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth` or `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-aliases` which process `ifcfg-ethX` configuration files to configure network interfaces.

When you check the scripts more carefully you will find out that this error appears after `arping` command which is trying to find out if the IP addresses specified in `ifcfg-ethX` files are unique in the network.

The scripts try to avoid of duplicate configurations in the network. `Ifconfig` doesn't care, it just add IP address to the interface. Check your configuration files twice as there may be some IP address twice.

Finally, it's worth to mention that you can put `ARPCHECK=no` directive to `ifcfg-ethX` file to disable this check.

Comment: Some how, someone had the same IP address as the server I was assigned, so the provisioning team double assigned an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out after reading dsmsk80 answer and looking in the ifup-eth script. The key line is this:

```
    /sbin/arping -c 2 -w 3 -D -I <INTERFACE> <VLAN>
```

So for the OP example:

```
    /sbin/arping -c 2 -w 3 -D -I eth0:1 192.168.0.2
```

Something I used this on recently returned this:

```
    > /sbin/arping -c 2 -w 3 -D -I eth0.1508 192.168.8.1
    ARPING 192.168.8.1 from 0.0.0.0 eth0.1508
    Unicast reply from 192.168.8.1 [00:1C:C4:A1:D8:39]  0.605ms
    Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
    Received 1 response(s)
```

I could then take this MAC (00:1C:C4:A1:D8:39) and look it up on the dynamic addresses section of my switch. This in turn told me the VLAN and port numbers of the interface that already used that IP.